# I Am not receiving Firestore callbacks in android

Tags: android, firebase, callback, google-cloud-firestore

I have been building an application with Firestore android for the past month and there is this bug that keeps bothering me and delaying me from launching my application.
While reading or writing data sometimes I am not receiving any callbacks like onComplete,onSuccess or onFailure this keeps my app keep loading forever while showing a progress dialog. After investigating this behaviour I noted it only occurs after the app has been in the foreground for some minutes while trying to open another activity from let's say the main activity, no data will be loaded and I don't receive any callback. But if I was to navigate very quickly to the second activity after opening the app, data will be loaded without any problem. Does the firestore client disconnect or what is happening and how would I solve this issue?

An example of how I load data

//FireStore

```
FirebaseFirestore mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

CollectionReference popular = mDatabase.collection("AvailableLocations").document("HL").collection("All");
        Query query = popular.orderBy("name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {


                        countiesList.add(document.getString("name"));
                    }


                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what does the exception say?

Comment: What is the error? And have you tried to use `addOnCompleteListener` without passing `this` as the first argument?

Comment: I don't get any exception since no callback is being called.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the form of [addOnCompleteListener()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) that takes an `Activity` as the first parameter.  This results in an *Activity-scoped* listener that is automatically removed when the `onStop()` method of the `Activity` is called.

It's not clear from your post which activity the posted code is in and how the activities interact. A likely explanation for the listener not firing is the the associationed activity (`this` in the code) is being stopped before the query completes.

Comment: Should I try running the queries without passing the activity contexts to the onComplete listener? but according to the documentation, this could lead to memory leakage if the listener continues listening even after the activity has stopped

Comment: Running the queries without the activity may not be the correct long-term solution, but would be worth trying as an experiment to see if you get better results.